# Lambda not working on array

Tags: vb.net, lambda

I have the following array

```
 Dim items() = {
                              New CheckedListBoxItem("NYC", False),
                              New CheckedListBoxItem("CHI", False),
                              New CheckedListBoxItem("PHL", False),
                              New CheckedListBoxItem("SFO", False),

                }
```

I am trying to query against it like this

```
        Try
            Dim item As CheckedListBoxItem = items.ToList().Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PHL")
            MsgBox(item.Value)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

I am getting the error

> Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: source

I also tried

```
 Dim item As CheckedListBoxItem = items.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Value.ToString() = "PHL")
```

What am i missing. I just need to query against the list to get an item and change it's checkedstate from false to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
item = items.ToList().Where(Function(x) x.Value = "PHL").First

MsgBox(item.Value)
```

`First` returns the First item from the collection or throws an exception if the collection is empty.

`FirstOrDefault` returns the First item from the collection or the default instance for the type if the collection is empty.